# Создание сущности или в каких случаях оправданы сеттеры?

Tags: php, entity

Как правило при работе с сущностями есть 2 подхода.

- вносить данные через конструктор
- вносить данные через сеттеры

Я выбрал подход с вводом данных через конструкторы, так как в нем нет нарушений целостности данных и он гарантирует имутабельность сущности.

Пример сущности:

```
<?php

class System
{
    private $id;
    private $alias;
    private $status;
    private $date;

    public function __construct
    (
        int $id,
        string $alias,
        Currencies $supportedCurrencies,
        SystemStatus $status,
        SystemServiceInfo $serviceInfo,
        Date $date
    )
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->alias = $alias;
        $this->supportedCurrencies = $supportedCurrencies;
        $this->status = $status;
        $this->serviceInfo = $serviceInfo;
        $this->date = $date;
    }

    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getAlias(): string
    {
        return $this->alias;
    }

    public function getStatus(): SystemStatus
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    public function getDate(): Date
    {
        return $this->date;
    }
}
```

в ходе этого я с толкнулся с такой проблемой, что когда нужно обновить 1 поле, нужно пересобрать сущность (да, тут конечно сеттер был бы к стати).  На ум приходит только одно фабрика + полное создание новой сущности.

Однако запутанность ситуации в том, что если я получаю сущность и мне нужно изменить в ней одно поле, для этого нужно создать новую сущность, а чтобы это сделать ее необходимо собрать из существующих данных, то появляется куча хелперов для перегонки сущности в массив и обратно.

Как в таких случаях (собирать сущность) лучше всего поступать ?

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд ответ в самом вопросе. Нафига для изменения одного свойства пересоздавать целый объект - это пустая трата ресурсов. Я делаю так:
Свойства без которых не может существовать объект передаются в конструктор. В зависимости от ситуации (предполагаю развитие или сложный класс со множеством свойств) один из параметров (а то и вообще один) типа массив. Через который могу передавать сколько угодно параметров, в том числе не обязательные для создания объекта.

Для свойств, которые могут изменяться в течении жизни объекта или имеют какой то алгоритм сохранения (проверки, вычисления и т.п.) делаю сеттеры. (которые использую и в конструкторе).

Если уж вам нравится идея с пересозданием объекта, тогда уж лучше сделать метод, например, init в который будет использовать и в конструкторе, и в том случае когда как вы сейчас пересоздаете объект

Answer (score 0):

Подойдет? (не уверен, что правильно понял суть вопроса)

```php
class System
{
    private $id;
    private $alias;
    private $status;
    private $date;

    public function __construct($params = array())
    {
        if (isset($params) && is_array($params) && count($params) > 0) {
            foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
                if (property_exists($this, $key) ) {
                    $this->$key = $value;     
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function getPropValue( $propName = null ) {
        $result = null;
        if ( !is_null( $propName ) && trim( $propName ) != '' && property_exists($this, $propName) ) {
            $result = $this->$propName;
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Создание с инициализацией внутренних переменных

```php
$model = new System(['id' => 1, 'alias' => 'test', 'non_existen_key' => 'value']);
```

Получение значения внутренней переменной

```php
$id = $model->getPropValue('id');
$date = $model->getPropValue('date');
```

По аналогии и `setPropValue`